# QML modify property alias from JS function in another qml file

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5

what I'm trying to do is create a separate QML file to handle called signals just for cleanliness sake.

I have:

`Signal.qml` (file that handles signals)

`Content.qml` (UI file with all components)

`Main.qml` (main QML file that houses the window for `Content.qml`)

I'm attempting to modify label text from `Content.qml` within `Signal.qml` inside of the signal function as shown:

property alias within `Content.qml`:
[image]

and then the signal function that needs to change label text:
[image]

There is no errors on output, just the label doesn't change like it should.

Signal:

```
import email 1.0
import "qrc:/ui/qml/component"
Email {
    onEmailListIndex: function(param1) {
        Content.progressBarLabelText = "testing"
        //label.text = qsTr(progressBar.value + " / " + progressBar.to + " Emails Sent")
        //progressBar.value = param1
    }

    onEmailListSize: function(param1) {
        //label.text = qsTr(progressBar.value + " / " + param1 + " Emails Sent")
        //progressBar.to = param1
    }
}
```

Content:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.15
Page {
    id: page
    width: 700
    height: 700
    anchors.fill: parent

    property alias progressBarLabelText: progressBarLabel.text


    Pane {
        id: mainContentPane
        visible: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        bottomPadding: 0
        horizontalPadding: 0
        padding: 0

        Rectangle {
            id: leftRectangle
            width: 100
            color: "#151515"
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0
            anchors.leftMargin: 0

            ScrollView {
                id: leftScrollView
                anchors.fill: parent
                ScrollBar.horizontal.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff
                ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff
                clip: true


                ItemDelegate {
                    id: statusButton
                    x: 0
                    y: 99
                    width: 100
                    height: 100
                    text: qsTr("Status")
                    highlighted: false
                    padding: 12
                    antialiasing: true
                    layer.smooth: false
                    display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
                    icon.source: "qrc:/ui/icon/flat-screen-monitor.png"
                }

                ItemDelegate {
                    id: emailButton
                    x: 0
                    y: 199
                    width: 100
                    height: 100
                    text: qsTr("Email")
                    layer.smooth: false
                    antialiasing: true
                    display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
                    onPressed: programSignals.workerThread()
                    icon.source: "qrc:/ui/icon/mail.png"
                }

                ItemDelegate {
                    id: settingsButton
                    x: 0
                    y: 300
                    width: 100
                    height: 100
                    text: qsTr("Settings")
                    layer.smooth: false
                    antialiasing: true
                    padding: 12
                    display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
                    icon.source: "qrc:/ui/icon/settings.png"
                }

                ItemDelegate {
                    id: homeButton
                    x: 0
                    y: 0
                    width: 100
                    height: 100
                    text: qsTr("Home")
                    layer.enabled: false
                    layer.smooth: false
                    display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
                    antialiasing: true
                    padding: 12
                    onPressed: statusPane.visible=false
                    icon.source: "qrc:/ui/icon/home.png"
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rightRectangle
            color: "#000000"
            anchors.left: leftRectangle.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.leftMargin: 101
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0
            anchors.rightMargin: 0


            ScrollView {
                id: statusPane
                anchors.fill: parent
                clip: false
                ScrollBar.horizontal.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff
                ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff
                ProgressBar {
                    id: emailProgressBar
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.bottomMargin: 618
                    anchors.leftMargin: 107
                    anchors.topMargin: 664
                    anchors.rightMargin: 107
                    from: 0
                }

                Label {
                    id: progressBarLabel
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    text: "lol"
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    anchors.bottomMargin: 592
                    anchors.topMargin: 680
                    anchors.leftMargin: 107
                    anchors.rightMargin: 107
                }

            }

            ScrollView {
                id: homePane
                visible: false
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Main:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.15
import email 1.0
import "component"
import "signal"
Window {
    id: window
    height: 700
    width: 700
    minimumHeight: 700
    minimumWidth: 700
    visible: true
    color: "#000000"
    title: qsTr("Email Program")
    Universal.theme: Universal.Dark
    Universal.accent: Universal.Violet
    Content {
        id: programContent
    }
    Signal{
        id: programSignals
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't show images of code. Copy and paste your code into your post.

Comment: Do you have an actual instance of `Content`? You really need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Edited the post. and I should note, "onEmailListIndex" is called everytime I click on the "Email" item delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reference the *instance* of Content (`programContent`) from the Signal file (instead of the *type*):

```
import email 1.0
import "qrc:/ui/qml/component"

Email {
    property var theContent
    onEmailListIndex: function(param1) {
        theContent.progressBarLabelText = "testing"
    }

}
```

and then from Window.qml supply it:

```
Content {
    id: programContent
}
Signal{
    id: programSignals
    theContent: programContent
}
```